# Vertically centered, Absolutely positioned child force parent height to match

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, height

I'd like to have a vertically centered div, inside a min-height parent div. I use this code to vertically center my div:

```
.parent {
    width:100%;
    min-height: 25vh;
    max-height: auto;
    position: relative; /* so center-area can be positioned absolute */
    display: inline-block;
    background:lightblue;
}
center-area {/* let it fill the whole container */
    position: absolute;  top: 0;  bottom: 0;  left: 0;  right: 0;
    display: inline-block;
}    
.center-area:before {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 100%;
}
.centered {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size:18px;
    background:green;
    margin:20px;
}
```

Perhaps some JS is needed? I'd like the blue, parent div's height to move with the child's height...

I realize the issue is that the child is absolutely positioned so that I can vertically align it, but when the content is greater than the parent div's height allows, I'd like the parent dive to lengthen down the page to accommodate... I hope that makes sense.

here is my JSfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/mr_antlers/8s8bhzd6/

Thanks in advance for your advice!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you please provide an image of what it should look like clicked and unclicked?

Comment: Does this have to be done with pure CSS? I can only think solution with javascript if all requirements need to be met.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried using `display:table-cell` for `.parent`, and `vertical-align: middle` for `.centered`, remove `.center-area`?

```js
$('.addContent').click(
    function(el) {
        $(el.target.parentElement).append('<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam consequat quam bibendum nibh cursus viverra. Duis suscipit bibendum faucibus. Praesent sit amet lectus sapien, ut dignissim augue. Aliquam sollicitudin nisi a nunc lobortis mollis. Phasellus vitae dolor ac orci porttitor lacinia at at augue. In dui eros, sodales ac gravida at, adipiscing rhoncus dolor. In tellus purus, scelerisque eu suscipit venenatis, tincidunt sit amet risus. Nunc sed nibh eu neque mattis varius in eget erat. Etiam sit amet felis lacus, placerat tincidunt dolor.</p>');
    }
);
```

```css
.parent {
    width:100%;
    min-height: 25vh;
    max-height: auto;
    position: relative; /* so center-area can be positioned absolute */
    display: table-cell;
    background:lightblue;
}

.centered {
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size:18px;
    background:green;
    margin:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myModule">
<div class="parent">
  <!-- <div class="center-area"> -->
      <div class="centered"><p><button class="addContent">add content</button><strong>This content is vertically centered inside this div... </strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam consequat quam bibendum nibh cursus viverra. Duis suscipit bibendum faucibus. Praesent sit amet lectus sapien, ut dignissim augue.</p>
          <div style="clear: both"></div>
      </div>
  <!-- </div> -->
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: `min-height: 25vh;` of `.parent` seems to be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

You can set `.parent` `background` to `transparent`, set the `border` property of `.centered` to `50px /* or other value, e.g., 75px, 100px */ solid lightblue`

```
html,
body {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.parent {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 25vh;
  max-height: auto;
  position: relative;
  /* so center-area can be positioned absolute */
  display: inline-block;
  background: transparent;
}

center-area {
  /* let it fill the whole container */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}

.center-area:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 100%;
}

.centered {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: green;
  z-Index: 1;
  border: 50px solid lightblue;
}

.clear_both {
  clear: both;
}
```

```js
$('.addContent').click(
  function(el) {
    $(el.target.parentElement).append('<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam consequat quam bibendum nibh cursus viverra. Duis suscipit bibendum faucibus. Praesent sit amet lectus sapien, ut dignissim augue. Aliquam sollicitudin nisi a nunc lobortis mollis. Phasellus vitae dolor ac orci porttitor lacinia at at augue. In dui eros, sodales ac gravida at, adipiscing rhoncus dolor. In tellus purus, scelerisque eu suscipit venenatis, tincidunt sit amet risus. Nunc sed nibh eu neque mattis varius in eget erat. Etiam sit amet felis lacus, placerat tincidunt dolor.</p>');
  }
);
```

```css
html,
body {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.parent {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 25vh;
  max-height: auto;
  position: relative;
  /* so center-area can be positioned absolute */
  display: inline-block;
  background: transparent;
}

center-area {
  /* let it fill the whole container */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}

.center-area:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 100%;
}

.centered {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: green;
  z-Index: 1;
  border: 50px solid lightblue;
}

.clear_both {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="center-area">
    <!--
    -->
    <div class="centered">
      <p>
        <button class="addContent">add content</button><strong>This content is vertically centered inside this div... </strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam consequat quam bibendum nibh cursus viverra. Duis suscipit bibendum faucibus. Praesent sit
        amet lectus sapien, ut dignissim augue.</p>
      <div style="clear: both"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/8s8bhzd6/2/

Comment: I dont think yours is a dynamic solution: https://jsfiddle.net/8s8bhzd6/4/  If the content is small, then everything changes.

Comment: Not quite right... I wanted the orginal to center vertically in a much bigger div... THEN , if content was added which meant it eventually became taller than the parent container, the parent container "broke", shed it's position to become static or relative... thus, it's height would be affected by it's child div... no longer absolute positioned.

Answer (score 1):

I think I've worked out a solution myself with a bit of research... I'll test it and post it here in case it helps someone else.

I'll get back to you!

Comment: If you have found an answer here please mark it as answered.